# How to pass a variable into a .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use parameters to put a variable into a .innerHTML. However, whenever I try to pass something in, it tends to give me an error because it's trying to find the innerHTML of a nonexistent item. I want the inner HTML to be customizable for several different functions.

```
function roll(type, num, type2){
    var total = (Math.floor(Math.random()*type)+1)
    var total2 = total * num;
    type2.innerHTML = total2;
}

d20button.onclick = function(){
    roll(19,1, 'd20p');
}
```

So the idea is that when I use different onclick buttons, I can pass in different variables depending on what the user enters. However, instead of using d20p.innerHTML, it keeps using type2.innerHTML. I'm wondering if there is a way to make it use d20p.innerHTML, while also leaving it open for other options.

Comment: This rolls once and multiplies which is going to wildly skew your random values. This has an even distribution across 1..20 when what you want is a pyramid or bell-curve shape for multiple rolls. Combining N rolls is not the same as one roll multiplied by N.

Comment: Oh. I'm not really looking for advice on that part. That is something I want to figure out myself. I'm mostly just looking for how to change that .innerHTML

Comment: @NicholasVoss `'d20p'` is id of the element you want to change html?

Comment: yes. That is the id I want to change.

Comment: Please post your attempt at using `innerHTML`. We typically need a [mcve]

Comment: `roll(19,1, document.getElementById('d20p'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'d20p'` is string which is passed as `type2` in `roll`. Strings donot have any property named `innerHTML` so you should use `document.getElementById()` before accessing `innerHTML`

```
function roll(type, num, type2){
    var total = (Math.floor(Math.random()*type)+1)
    var total2 = total * num;
    document.getElementById(type2).innerHTML = total2;
}
```

If you want to change the `innerHTML` of any button clicked then you can pass `this` as parameter from `onclick` event which will refer to the button clicked.

```
d20button.onclick = function(){
    roll(19,1,this);
} 
function roll(type, num, type2){
    var total = (Math.floor(Math.random()*type)+1)
    var total2 = total * num;
    type2.innerHTML = total2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I just started my account. How do I accept something?

Comment: Nevermind. Just found the button. It says to wait 2 minutes so I'll accept it then.

Comment: `this` would be the button itself. You want that? Note that is also the `.innerHTML` of the `<button>`, not `.value`.

Comment: @StackSlave I was responding to a comment that has apparently been deleted. I understand the answer.